# Azure Web app cannot find views of .NET Core 2.1 App

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET Core 2.1 app which is deployed to Azure Web Apps. The app works locally, also when using the release mode, but on Azure it's giving an error about missing view / cshtml files. When I look at the source code deployed to Azure, you see the Product.Views.dll. It somehow seems that on Azure the compiled views are not loaded?

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: 2.1 is now available on App Service as of 5/31/2018 (see https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/113). Please try again.

**Original**:
.NET Core 2.1 is not yet available on App Service, so I would not expect it to work yet. Note that 2.1 has not even been officially announced yet (though it will be soon).

Comment: I'm using the extension to load the runtime, which works for us the past couple of weeks.

Comment: I'm confused about [this discussion](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/47) then. Is it not supported in any capacity?

Comment: This discussion is about 2.1 **RC1**, not the final 2.1.

Comment: It turns out the problem was the fact that we were using preview2 vs RC1 of .NET Core 2.1. In my local development environment I was using preview2 while VSTS was already on RC1. Azure again was using preview2 because we installed 2.1 early with help of an extension. The problem was caused by a difference in the *.deps.json file that was generated during the build with both versions of .NET Core 2.1 runtime. The fix was moving to RC1/RTM everywhere. Your comment helped to find the solution!

Comment: Great! Note that now that GA is out, you should use that instead of RC1.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is known to me for randomly adding weird lines to .csproj files. During the process of finding the bug I stumbled upon on these few lines below in my project file. My web app worked smooth locally, but when I was publishing it on Azure it couldn't find one particular view. **Getting rid of** these lines solved my problem.

**.csproject file:**

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="Views\Groups\Invitations.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <UpToDateCheckInput Remove="Views\Groups\Invitations.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Views\Groups\Invitations.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="Views\Groups\Invitations.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```